# Why Bootstrap grid system doesn't support 5 columns by default?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, system

I have seen there are lots of workarounds to make Bootstrap to support 5 columns grid, but there isn't a proper explanation why it doesn't support 5 columns in the first place.

Instead of making things work I think it is important to know how the Bootstrap structure works. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it a simple logic bootstrap grid system equal to 12 column if we divide 12col to 5col so result 2.4 and bootstrap not provide to 2.4 col you have to make your own html or css or search on  google  i hope it help you

or try it
http://www.wearesicc.com/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

Simply because, Bootstrap follows a [12 column grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). *(and 12%5 !== 0)*
You're free to use other grid systems: 
[here's a list](http://designinstruct.com/web-design/responsive-css-grid/).
Or create your [own](http://j4n.co/blog/Creating-your-own-css-grid-system)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can have two 1 columns acting as margins, and then with the 10 left, you can have five 2 columns.